# How can I make this tree traversal more efficient?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, data-structures, tree

I have a project that processes a set of rules.  Currently a rule consists of one or more clauses, the syntax of which looks like so:

```
A
A & B
A & B & C
etc
```

This is codified as follows:

```
struct Rule {
    list<Clause*> Clauses;
};

bool ProcessRule(const Rule* Rule) {
    for (const auto& Clause : Rule->Clauses) {
        if (!ProcessClause(Clause)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am tasked with implementing a complimentary logical or construct, the syntax of which looks like so:

```
A
A & B
A | B
A & B & C
A & B | C
A | B & C
A | B | C
etc
```

I went with the most obvious approach and changed the implementation of the `Rule` structure from using a list to using a tree:

```
enum NodeType {
    LogicalAnd,
    LogicalOr,
    Leaf,
};

struct Node {
    NodeType Type;
};

struct LogicalNode : Node {
    list<Node*> Children;
};

struct LeafNode : Node {
    Clause* Clause;
};

struct Rule {
    Node* Root;
}

bool ProcessRule(const Rule* Rule) {
    return ProcessNode(Rule->Root);
}

bool ProcessNode(const Node* Node) {
    switch (Node->Type) {
        case LogicalAnd:
            for (const auto& Child : ((const LogicalNode*)Node)->Children) {
                if (!ProcessNode(Child)) return false;
            }
            return true;
        case LogicalOr:
            for (const auto& Child : ((const LogicalNode*)Node)->Children) {
                if (ProcessNode(Child)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        case Leaf:
            return ProcessClause(((const LeafNode*)Node)->Clause);
    }
}
```

It all seems pretty straightforward but the problem is a relatively severe degradation of performance using the exact same set of rules, on the order of 15% or so.  I've run both versions through a profiler and the degradation is due to the overhead of the `ProcessNode()` function, I assume due to the switch statement and function calls as `ProcessRule()` is called millions of times.  Is there some way to mitigate this overhead?  It seems a bit excessive so I feel like I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: It probably comes from the indirection introduced by the tree structure. You might want to try to replace some pointers by direct containment or try to represent your tree in some flat array, depending on how much you want to invest in the optimization.

Comment: Example of flat representation is [polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation). You might want to use some additional indexes there to be able to skip some parts of the expression, when they are not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the switch and add `AndNode` and `OrNode` classes, and use a virtual function with suitable overrides.

Comment: My understanding is that in modern compilers there's negligible difference between the two approaches but I suppose it's worth profiling to find out.

Comment: I just profiled this approach and there was in fact negligible difference.